# re-rendering a component React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

New to React and am trying to get a typing animation along with a backspace animation using the `react-typing-animation` library.

I have a list of words that I want this typing animation to iterate over with each item appearing for 3 seconds. This code does that for replacing each word:

```
const items = ['mattress','loft kit', 'skis', 'boxes', 'clothes', 'furniture'];
var count = 0;

export class Header extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {     
      setInterval(this.timer, 3000);
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {      
        currentItem: items[count]
      }

      this.timer = this.timer.bind(this)
    }

    timer() {
      count += 1;
      if(count < items.length) {
        this.setState({
            currentItem: items[count]
        })
      }
    }

    render() {
      return(
       {this.state.currentItem}
      )
    }
}
```

Using the `<Typing>` component from the library I generated this code:

```
<Typing> 
 <Typing.Delay ms={1000}/> 
 {this.state.currentItem} 
 <Typing.Backspace count = {20} delay={2000}/> 
</Typing>
```

This code works for the animation I want but only does it for the first item in the list of items. Does this component have to render again? If so, how would I include this in my `componentDidMount` method? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Move you`timer()` code inside `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @Umesh how should `this.timer = this.timer.bind(this)` be modified? and `this.setState`?

Comment: count always start from 0 whenever timer is called

Comment: @Vivian really? How should I modify count to not start from 0 every time? Thought I avoided this, declaring it as a global

Comment: You can use state to contain the count instead of reading global. As I think because of JS closure, it will be 0. Would you be able to debug by putting a break point in the first line of timer fucntion?

Comment: The code looks fine on `codesandbox`. `Typing` could be the culprit here. What library is this typing using ?? More over the text change after each 3s and the delay in your typing component is 1s for each character I suppose.

Comment: @Prasanna I am not too sure, it is just a library I found that fit this problem. Any alternatives or ideas on how to fix this? thanks.

Comment: you could try reducing the delay between each character or alternatively increase the time between change of words and see if it helps. I am just assuming and not completely sure if it works

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to show how you can include timer inside `componentDidMount()`

```
const items =['mattress','loft kit', 'skis', 'boxes', 'clothes', 'furniture']

export class Header extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      let count = this.state.count 
      const intvl = setInterval( () => {
        if (count < items.length) {
          this.setState({currentItem: items[count]})
          this.setState({count: count += 1})
        }
      }, 3000)
      this.setState({interval: intvl})
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.state.interval)
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        currentItem: items.length,
        interval
      }
    }

    render() {
      return( <div>
       {this.state.currentItem}
       </div>
      )
    }
}
```